# Graficar datos json con ajax y google-api

Tags: ajax, google-chart-api

Tengo una función en mi controller la cual me da como resultado un json que necesito para graficar, el problema es que no tengo idea de como graficar todos los datos, solo me muestra el ultimo en la gráfica. Con console.log(result); veo que si me trae los datos pero solo me gráfica el ultimo.

```html
function grafica() {
 google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

 function drawChart() {
 var i;
   $.ajax({
   url: "/Indicadores/Grafica",
   type: "GET",
   ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function (result)
   {
   for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   console.log(result[i].Mes);
   console.log(result[i].Total);
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Task', 'Visitas por mes'],
       [result[i].Mes, result[i].Total]
   ]);     
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('Vchart'));
  chart.draw(data);
   }   
  },
  error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
  console.log(jqxhr.responseText);
  }
  });       
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos que quiero graficar (resultado de mi query sql server)

```html
Total Mes
3 A-Julio
50 D-Octubre
135 E-Noviembre
157 F-Diciembre
109 G-Enero
```

Comment: me puedes dar un sample de los datos para probar la grafica

Comment: @stanchacon osea los resultados de mi query??

Comment: Puedes ponerlos en el formato original, asi me ahorrar trabajo para adjuntarte un ejemplo

Comment: @stanchacon formato de que disculpa? no entiendo, de mi query?

Comment: la respuesta de tu ajax, si es JSON agregalo en formato json si es array en formato array

Comment: @stanchacon pues es json pero no entiendo como

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo he resuelto asi. Lo dejo aqui por si es de ayuda para alguien

```html
    function grafica() {
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);      

        function drawChart() {           
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Indicadores/Grafica",
                type: "GET",
                ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var arrSales = [['Mes', 'Total']];   

                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        arrSales.push([value.Mes, value.Total]);
                    });
                    var options = {
                        title: 'Visitas al mes',
                        curveType: 'function',
                        legend: { position: 'bottom', textStyle: { color: '#555', fontSize: 14 } }  
                    };                    
                    var figures = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrSales)
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('Vchart'));
                    chart.draw(figures, options); 

                },
                error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
                    console.log(jqxhr.responseText);
                }
            });           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente ejemplo lo realice teniendo en cuenta los siguientes puntos:

1. Suponiendo que la respuesta de la llamada ajax sea un objeto **JSON** se realiza la transformacion de este a un array de arrays que contiene especificaciones de elementos a crear en forma de objetos.
2. Cree una función que realiza dicho procedimiento por lo que es probable que solamente tomes el encapsulado de la función dentro de llamada **Ajax**.

```js
      function drawColumnChart(){
            //suponiendo que recibes un json la variable json es la respuesta de tu backend
      let json = [
      {mes:'Noviembre', total: 1200, anio: 2019},
      {mes:'Diciembre', total: 1350, anio: 2019},
      {mes:'Enero', total: 500, anio: 2019}
      ];
      //array es el inicializador que contiene las columnas y argumentos de tu grafico en el indice 0
      let array = [
        [ 'Name','Visitas' ,{role:'annotation'}, {role:'tooltip'}]
        ],
        // json_a_array es el mapeo de los elementos de tu json a array
       json_a_array = json.map((e)=>{
        return [
        ...[e.mes,e.total,e.anio,`${e.mes} ${e.anio} : ${e.total} visita(s)`]];
        });
       //seguidamente pasamos los valores de json_a_array a tu array de argumentos donde los indices que siguen despues de 0 son la data de la grafica
   json_a_array.map((e)=>{ array.push(e) });
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
              array
                );
// establecemos las opciones d ela grafica
        var options = {
          title: 'Visitas por mes',
          hAxis: {title: 'Meses', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
                tooltip: {legend:'none',isHtml:true, textStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}, showColorCode: true}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
       
      }
//cargamos la grafica
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawColumnChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Espero sea de ayuda si tienes alguna duda puedes consultarla

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto, gracias de antemano